# How to deploy axis2 + MyBatis

Tags: java, apache-axis, ibatis

I am trying to do webservice (I am quite new in Webservice under java). I am using netbeans.

Axis2 is having problem trying to locate the the xml configuration file for mybatis

Anyone can tell me how to successfully deploy mybatis configuration. Should I manually copy the configuration under .netbeans\6.8\apache-tomcat-6.0.20_base\webapps\axis2\WEB-INF\classes or there is any other setting?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your xml configuration file for ibatis in your classpath. I put it on my src folder and it workds

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The configuration files are in my source folder all the while. :). Somehow it doesn't get copied to myBatis path. So I manually copy the xml config.